# Eloquent Model is automatically converted to JSON

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-7, return-type

I have a very simple Eloquent model named `Player`. Something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'players';
}
```

I've created a function in my controller which is supposed to return all players as a JSON string.

```
private function getPlayers(): string
{
    $players = Player::get();
    return $players;
}
```

I later realised that I forgot to json_encode the `$players` variable, but apparently it doesn't matter, because it still returns json.

```
private function getPlayers(): string 
{
    $players = Player::get();
    echo gettype($players); //object
    return $players;
}

public function getPlayersType()
{
    $players = $this->getPlayers();
    echo gettype($players); //string
}
```

How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the `string` Return type declaration.

The documentation of [PHP 7 Return type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) states (emphasis mine):

> Strict typing also has an effect on return type declarations. In the default weak mode, returned **values will be coerced to the correct type** if they are not already of that type. In strong mode, the returned value must be of the correct type, otherwise a TypeError will be thrown.

#### __toString()

If you implement a `__toString()` method in a class, it can be coerced to a string with a string return type.

In this case, `Player::get()` returns an instance of the `Collection` class, which implements a `__toString()` method which json encodes the collection

#### Illuminate\Support\Collection.php

```
/**
 * Convert the collection to its string representation.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->toJson();
}
```

#### Strict typing

To disable this functionality, you'll have to enable [Strict typing](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) by adding a strict type declaration to your code

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

Be aware that this also enforces strict typing on type hinting for function parameters.

Comment: Great answer, very well explained!